# 3W infrared LEDs not living up to 500mA-700mA - not even close

Tags: led, low-power

Here are the specs:

1. Emitted Color:  850nm
2. Forward Voltage (VF): 1.5-1.7V
3. DC Forward Current (IF): 500-700mA
4. Maximum Pulse Voltage: 2.2V
5. List item

But after hooking to power supply (which I first set at 100mA just to be safe and 1.5V) it would only use 18mA. I increased to 1.7V at 300mA and got about 24mA. Also with with my test light I decided to increase it to 2.2V at 500mA set on power supply, and only got about 80mA.

Why can I not get even close to the 500-700mA as advertised?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the datasheet?

Comment: Did you check the voltage with a meter, preferably at the LED terminals?  Meters on power supplies, or worse, dial settings on power supplies, just aren't reliable.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of your circuit? There may be an extra/missing component somewhere.

Comment: Item from ebay or aliexpress?

Comment: Does your voltage measurement include the ammeter drop or not? Even in seemingly trivial circuits such as this one, a schematic can help.

Comment: 1. The light is lighting up, but I have to use my cell phone to see it. 2. It was bought on ebay and that was the specs given. 3. no schematics, it was hooked up to power supply with constant current. The Power supply lists what it was using, But I did at one point put a amp meter in between the power supply and led and all it did is confirm what the power supply was showing.

Comment: is it bright enough to show up on a wall in a dark room?  ....... you may have to destructively test one of the LEDs ...... attach a heatsink the LED .....  set current limiting to 400mA and slowly turn up the voltage ..... keep watching with the phone camera .... also monitor the LED temperature

Comment: To be clear, you cannot "set" both the voltage and current at the same time.  You can set a voltage or a current, but the other will be determined by the load.  If you're talking about a generable purpose variable benchtop power supply, note that the voltage and current knobs set upper limits, so if you limit current to 100mA, you will only achieve 100mA if the voltage setting is high enough.

Comment: Yes, you can't set both, but I did play with both constant current and constant voltage. I would try one, then try the other.. Unless I cranked the voltage Higher then spec, I could not get much visibility(using a camera to see) and not much higher then  120mA. I'm going to try what TimWescott recommended and just keep current constant, and keep cranking the voltage.. So far its never hit the max current I set..

Comment: VTC unclear until datasheet can be found. Now there's not even a product code or a manufacturer. I don't see how 700 mA at 2.2 volt can ever amount to 3 watt.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @TimWescott s comment, I presume you have a circuit which looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faa8NW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where V1 is a current-limited variable power supply.

Rather than depend on the supply voltage meter, try the following. With the voltage set to five volts or more and the current limit set to zero, connect a DMM set to measure current as the power supply load. Increase the current limit setting until you have something like 200 mA being provided. Short circuit the output and disconnect the meter. Now connect the LED and release the short circuit. Use the DMM to measure the LED forward voltage. Good power supplies have fairly accurate output meters, but there is no guarantee that you have a good one.

Alternatively, if you don't want to depend on your current limit function, get a 100 ohm, 5 watt resistor. Spend a little extra and get a 1% unit. Set the current limit to something like 1 amp. Connect the LED like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fayeG6.png)</sup>

Now set the supply voltage to something like 12 volts. You should be reading a load current of about 100 mA. Now measure the LED forward voltage.

Comment: Actually what you described above "connect a DMM set to measure current as the power supply load" is something I did. It verified what the Power supply was reading. Also I did keep the constant current then kept increasing the voltage up to about 3v (which I did not dare go above). At that point it was drawing close to 100ma or more, plus it showed very bright in the camera. But It was my understanding this is supposed to operate at 1.5V at 100mA.

Comment: Yes but **did you actually measure the voltage**?

Comment: @ShermStebbins - Look - do you trust your power supply to put out a constant current at limit or not? If you do, then you can set the voltage at anything you want without worrying about the voltage at the load. So, "which I did not dare go above" suggests that you don't know how your supply works. So follow the procedure I set out. And actually measure the voltage. Also, get a better meter. If your meter is, as you say 10k input impedance it cannot be a digital meter, but has to be an old (very old) analog unit. Get rid of it and get a real DMM.

Comment: Yes, I've even put the DMM (which I have many and was using my most trusted on)., but I did play with both constant current and constant voltage. I would try one, then try the other.. Unless I cranked the voltage Higher then spec, I could not get much visibility(using a camera to see) and not much higher then  120mA.. Again also double checking with DMM. I will try your advise I do have several spares so I can push one all the way till it dies.. It will be interesting to see what voltage that is at..

Comment: @ShermStebbins - Ack! From a comment, "The light is lighting up, but I have to use my cell phone to see it." and from another, "Unless I cranked the voltage Higher then spec, I could not get much visibility"  Well, yes. You do realize, I hope, that 850 nm is not visible to the naked eye? And cell phones are limited to approximately visible response? The fact that you can see the LED at all on your cell phone is just an indication that it has some response in near IR. Do not pay any attention AT ALL to the apparent brightness of the LED.

Comment: To my recollection consumer application CMOS light sensors have an IR filter to block NIR radiation, unless they're designed as part of a IR security camera system.  A phone camera will most likely have such an IR filter.

Comment: @isdi - Of course they do. If they don't, the images they produce will look profoundly weird. Look up "IR photography". A straightforward way to get into the field is to have a camera modified by removing the IR filter.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yes, years ago I removed one from a logitech to do some quick astrophotography stuff, improved the sensitivity to starlight and moons which is what I was after.

Comment: @isdi - And what did portraits and landscapes look like? Would you buy such a camera for general (non-astrophotography) use?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I knew removing the filter would destroy the original purpose of the camera- didn't expect to see color as such after that, but I didn't care about that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice.. I set CC to  500ma then cranked the voltage till I hit CC and it took about 2.6v to hit it.. Looking at the brightness in the camera, It was very bright.. I guess my question is why don't they list a higher voltage on it since the 1.5-1.7 only hits about 80ma

Comment: @ShermStebbins - Is 2.6 volts as measured with a DMM, or is it the voltage indicated on the power supply?